# ls -lS on the output of find doesn't sort the output

Tags: find, ls, sort

As we know, `ls -S` will list all files ordered by size.

What I'm trying to do is to list all files in the directory `/usr` ordered by size. So I executed the command as below:

```
find /usr -type f -exec ls -lS {} \;
```

However, it doesn't seem that this command lists all files ordered by size... `-S` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've explicitly asked `find` to search for files (`-type f`), and when you find one, you've asked it to execute `ls -lS` on it. You can't even fix this with the GNU find extension of `+` to pass more than one matching file at a time, as there may (likely) be too many files to pass to `ls` at once.

Instead, using GNU find, ask it to print the size of the file and the filename, then pass it to `sort`, all null-delimited.

```
find /usr -type f -printf "%s %p\n\0"|sort -zn
```

Sample output:

```
0 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/__init__.py
0 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_debian-0.1.30.egg-info/requires.txt
0 /usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/__init__.py
... output omitted ...
24013304 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6/cc1plus
25675008 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.57.1
49547156 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.9.so.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output in the format of `ls -l`, then you can use

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \;|sort -n -k5
```

Sample

```
$ find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \;|sort -n -k5
-rw-rw----+ 1 utsav utsav 0 Mar  6 02:23 ./file5.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 utsav utsav 12 Mar  6 01:57 ./a.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 utsav utsav 15 Mar  6 02:10 ./foo.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 utsav utsav 15 Mar  6 02:11 ./c.txt
-rw-rw----+ 1 utsav utsav 27 Mar  6 01:57 ./b.txt
```